# Oracle. CAST COLLECT for date datatype

Tags: oracle

Consider the types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE   TYPE date_array AS  TABLE OF DATE; 
CREATE OR REPLACE   TYPE number_array AS  TABLE OF NUMBER;
CREATE OR REPLACE   TYPE char_array AS  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(80);
```

Queries:

```
WITH q AS
 (SELECT LEVEL ID,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) + LEVEL MyDate,
         to_char(LEVEL) STRING
  FROM   dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5)
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(ID) AS number_array)
FROM   q;
```

return collection of numbers

```
WITH q AS
 (SELECT LEVEL ID,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) + LEVEL MyDate,
         to_char(LEVEL) STRING
  FROM   dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5)
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(STRING) AS char_array)
FROM   q;
```

return collection of strings

```
WITH q AS
 (SELECT LEVEL ID,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) + LEVEL MyDate,
         to_char(LEVEL) STRING
  FROM   dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5)
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(MyDate) AS date_array)
FROM   q
```

return error `invalid datatype`.

Can anyone explain why the Date datatype behaves differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my findings... it seems you are facing a bug caused by the fact that calculated dates seem to have a different internal representation from "database" dates. I did find a workaround, so keep on reading.

On my oracle dev installation (Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production) I am experiencing your same problem.

BUT... If I create a *physical* table containing your test data:

```
create table test_data as 
SELECT LEVEL ID,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) + LEVEL MyDate,
       to_char(LEVEL) STRING
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5
```

and then run the "cast collect" operator on this physical table, it works as expected:

```
-- this one works perfectly
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(MyDate) AS date_array) from test_data
```

but all these examples still do NOT work:

```
-- here I just added 1 .. and it doesn't work
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(MyDate + 1) AS date_array) 
from test_data

-- here I am extracting sysdate, instead of a physical column... and it doesn't work
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(sysdate) AS date_array) 
from test_data
```

**It feels like oracle doesn't think that *calculated* dates are the same thing of *physical* dates**

So, I tried to "persuade" oracle that the data I am providing is actually a normal DATE value, using an explicit cast... and EUREKA! this does the job correctly:

```
  WITH q AS
  (SELECT LEVEL ID,                                     
          -- this apparently unnecessary cast does the trick
          CAST( TRUNC(SYSDATE) + LEVEL AS DATE) MyDate, 
          to_char(LEVEL) STRING
   FROM   dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5)
 SELECT CAST(COLLECT(MyDate) AS date_array)
 FROM   q
```

**Yes... but why??**

It really seems that these two values are not exactly the same thing, even if the values we see are actually the same:

```
 select sysdate, cast (sysdate as date) from dual
```

So I dug in the internal representation of the two values applying the "dump" function to both of them:

```
 select dump(sysdate), dump(cast (sysdate as date)) from dual
```

and these are the results I got:

```
DUMP(SYSDATE                    )  -> Typ=13 Len=8: 226,7,11,9,19,20,47,0   
DUMP(CAST(SYSDATEASDATE) as DUAL)  -> Typ=12 Len=7: 120,118,11,9,20,21,48
```

Internally they look like two totally different data types! one is type 12 and the other is type 13... and they have different length and representation.

Anyway I discovered something more.. it seems someone else has noticed this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4122627

The question has an answer pointing to this document: http://psoug.org/reference/datatypes.html

which contains a lengthy note about dates... an excerpt of it reads:

> "What happened? Is the information above incorrect or does the DUMP()
>   function not handle DATE values? No, you have to look at the "Typ="
>   values to understand why we are seeing these results.  ". The datatype
>   returned is 13 and not 12, the external DATE datatype. This occurs
>   because we rely on the TO_DATE function! External datatype 13 is an
>   internal c-structure whose length varies depending on how the
>   c-compiler represents the structure. Note that the "Len=" value is 8
>   and not 7. Type 13 is not a part of the published 3GL interfaces for
>   Oracle and is used for date calculations mainly within PL/SQL
>   operations. Note that the same result can be seen when DUMPing the
>   value SYSDATE."

Anyway, I repeat: I think this is a bug, but at least I found a workaround: use an explicit cast to DATE.